Cannot authenticate Azure Virtual Desktop Host with FSLogix Storage Accounts Entra ID
My main problem is I have an Entra ID Authentication inside the host pool on AVD, so I can log into the VMs using my Entra ID.
The next thing I wanted to set up was FSLogix to create a simple profile container, I created a storage account that only has access from the network where my host pool is located and created a File Share.
I followed the FSLogix docs and ran into a problem, I cannot mount the new file share onto my PC using my Entra ID credentials.
I can however mount it using the access key of my storage account.
I also set the registry up with the ones from the documentation
Going into the Event Viewer on one of my VMs I get this



Status
Details
Event ID




Error 6/27/2024 11:23:55 AM:
LoadProfile failed. Version: 2.9.8884.27471 User: <<USERNAME>>. SID: <<SID>>. SessionId: 2. FrxStatus: 31 (The user name or password is incorrect.)
26


Information 6/27/2024 11:23:55 AM:
Profile load: Status: 27  Reason: 5  Error: 1326  Username: <<USERNAME>>  SID: <<SID>>
25


Error 6/27/2024 11:23:55 AM:
Operation: FSLogixFindFile, SessionId: 2, ErrorCode: 1326
38


Error 6/27/2024 11:23:55 AM:
FindFile failed for path: \\<<STORAGE NAME>>.file.core.windows.net\<<SHARE>\<<USERNAME-SID>>\Profile*.VHDX (The user name or password is incorrect.)
26


Information 6/27/2024 11:23:55 AM:
Removed the local profile for user with SID <<SID>>.
59


Error 6/27/2024 11:23:08 AM:
Failed to get computer's group SIDs
26


Error 6/27/2024 11:23:07 AM:
Querying computer's fully qualified distinguished name failed. (Configuration information could not be read from the domain controller, either because the machine is unavailable, or access has been denied.)
26


Information 6/27/2024 11:23:01 AM:
The FSLogix service (frxsvc) has loaded successfully.
8



I've given myself the roles:
Storage File Data Privileged Contributor
Storage File Data SMB Share Contributor
The storage account inherits them from the resource group
The output of
dsregcmd /status

+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Device State                                                         |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+

             AzureAdJoined : YES
          EnterpriseJoined : NO
              DomainJoined : NO
           Virtual Desktop : NOT SET
               Device Name : avd-host-vm-0


Thanks.

You may follow the MS DOC: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-desktop/fslogix-profile-container-configure-azure-files-active-directory?tabs=adds

Did you ever figure this out? I have the same issue!
